# on grid view, when updating an app, this one is taken at the end of the grid

Tags: google-play-store, launcher, home-screen-shortcuts, app-drawer

In the app drawer, when an application is updated, its icon goes to the last page, in the last free place... Is that normal? Is there a way to make the application stay where I put it? I mean, I sort everything in folder, but after some days (and some updates) many apps are taken to the last page, outside the folder... This is annoying...

This happens on **Samsung S2**  **Android 4.0.3**

I try to explain it better:
in the app drawer, i have a lot of apps, i usually order them in "pages" and each page in folders, so i would like to have the page with all the folders containing all the "work apps" such as google drive, the email client, some editors and so on, then, i've got another page, with all the folders for all the games, i mean, i've a folder with arcade games, with 3d games and so on... now, after few days in this fantastic order, some of those applications get updated, automatically, by google play, you know, when there is that notification "application xxxx is been updated!", you know what i mean. well, when this happens, that particular application is deleted from the folder it belongs, and i found her in the last page, in the last free place, the example i've made has 2 pages, one for work apps, and one for games, if something gets an update, i'll find that app in the games pages, outside any folder, hanging around and looking at me... :D

Comment: Your question is unclear. _Where_ are you seeing this updated icon? The app drawer? A home screen? The list of apps in Settings? The list of apps in the Play Store?

Comment: If you're looking for your shift key, there should be one left to your space key ;) I fixed that. And most likely you're speaking of the app drawer? Then it would help to know what launcher you are using.

Comment: no launchers, it is the "default" one